# Checking concrete type of inheriting classes

Tags: c#, oop, class-design

Let's say I have a couple of classes:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    //....
}

public class ChildClassA : BaseClass
{
    //....
}

public class ChildClassB : BaseClass
{
    //....
}
```

Now I have another class which uses the child classes above:

```
public class Program
{
    private Type _type;
    private ChildClassA _childA = GetChildClassA();
    private ChildClassB _childB = GetChildClassB();

    public void MethodOne()
    {
        if(_type == typeof(ChildClassA))
            DoSomething(_childA);
        else if(_type == typeof(ChildClassB))
            DoSomething(_childB);
    }

    public void MethodTwo()
    {
        if(_type == typeof(ChildClassA))
            DoSomething(_childA);
        else if(_type == typeof(ChildClassB))
            DoSomething(_childB);
    }
}
```

Let's say I have the if clause inside `MethodOne` and `MethodTwo` over and over again in my code, how can I make this cleaner? With an interface, I can just declare one class variable `IBaseClass` and assign `_childA` or `_childB` to it. But with inherited classes, this isn't possible. Is there some other way to get the same result? So basically I would end up with something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    private IBaseClass _child = GetChildClass();

    public void MethodOne()
    {
        DoSomething(_child);
    }

    public void MethodTwo()
    {
        DoSomething(_child);
    }
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, I can't use interfaces as all the classes have already been implemented since a long time ago and refactoring them would be a huge undertaking. So I am basically looking for doing something similar with base and child classes.

EDIT2: Here is what I meant with my comment on HimBromBeere's answer:

```
private void DoSomething(BaseClass baseC)
{
    var childA = baseC as ChildClassA;

    if (childA != null)
        childA.DoSomethingA();

    var childB = baseC as ChildClassB;

    if(childA != null)
        childB.DoSomethingB();
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just pass both children as their base class?

Comment: You won´t need an interface, as you already have a common base-class. So just change `private IBaseClass _child = GetChildClass();
` to `private BaseClass _child = GetChildClass();
`.

Comment: What is `DoSomething()`? Where does `_type` get its value? You don't need to check the type of an object if you use overloading. The question in its current form is unclear and the code *doesn't* help

Comment: Does `_type` change?  If not just inject the child class that you need instead of trying to figure out which one to use.

Comment: Use `BaseClass` as the type of `_child`, and you will be able to assign `ChildClassA` and `ChildClassB` to it. And, you need overriding method, so you won't need type checking anymore.

Comment: Without knowing what `DoSomething` is and how it depends on the provided instance, it´s hard to indicate why you even need to do the switch.

Comment: Can you modify `ChildClassA` and `ChildClassB` to implement a common base-member which you could then call within `DoSomething`?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos _type would get it's value through a constructor and create ChildA or ChildB accordingly. Maybe the question would have been better if I just checked ChildA and ChildB if they are null and left out _type as it's just confusing.

Comment: @HimBromBeere no, not really. The code I am working on is 10 years old and has gone through more hands than a joint on Snoop Dogg's birthday.

Comment: If the implementation of `DoSomething` is totally different in A and B then make it an abstract method in the base class and implement it in A and B separately. If it has common code, move that code to a method in the [abstract] base class, but don't use if statements to switch on type like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to indicate at runtime which behaviour to use by switching on the actual type, which is what polymorphism is about.

You won´t need an interface, as you already *have* a common base-class. So just change `private IBaseClass _child = GetChildClass()` to `private BaseClass _child = GetChildClass()`:

```
public class Program
{
    private BaseClass _child = GetChildClass();

    public void MethodOne()
    {
        DoSomething(_child);
    }

    public void MethodTwo()
    {
        DoSomething(_child);
    }
}
```

This assumes `DoSomething` just expects a `BaseClass` as parameter.

Comment: Let's say ChildA and ChildB have different method implementations (`ChildClassA` has `DoSomethingA()` and `ChildClassB` has `DoSomethingB()`  and I want to call them inside `DoSomething()`. I would still need to check whether `_child` is of type `ChildClassA` or `ChildClassB` inside `DoSomething()` so I can cast them to their concrete types and call the corresponding method. Is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: @LeonidasFett Then again: please add what `DoSomething` does and how it depends on the two types.

Comment: @LeonidasFett No, just define base method and mark it `abstract`. Then implement it inside your child classes.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn It seems to me that `ChildA` has `DoSomethingA` and `ChildB` has `DoSomethingB`, where both methods have different names and thus don´t implement the same base-method.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I updated my question. And yes, you are correct. ;)

Comment: @LeonidasFett While my code above won´t solve the need to switch in `DoSomething` it does prevent you from switching in `MethodOne` and `MethodTwo`.

Comment: That's correct and that was my original question. I guess I just need some more practice with class design and I will get used to designing them. :)